# Permission denied while installing matlab in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: permissions, software-installation, matlab

I'm installing Matlab in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS by using terminal commands.
As mentioned in installation guide I am entering the following command:

```
/path_to_dvd/install &
```

but when I enter the command it shows permission denied.

```
$ /home/pawan/Documents/matlab/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/install &
[1] 19068
bash: /home/pawan/Documents/matlab/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/install: Permission denied
```

I have mounted my .iso file and given path of that as well but it didn't work and
I gave path of my .iso also.

Comment: What about using `sudo`?

Comment: Like the ^ user said, your command would be `sudo /path_to_dvd/install &`

Comment: I doubt "sudo" is the solution. I see a flaw: `/home/pawan/Documents/matlab/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/install` should not be a path to a DVD but to a downloaded file.  Please provide a reference to the installation method. Most likely you need to do `cd /home/pawan/Documents/matlab/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/` and then `./install`. Also make sure install is an executable.

Comment: Whenever I run the path with sudo command, it returns me a number in brackets followed by a four digit number i.e. [1] : 6435, [2] : 7482...

Comment: post the error report.

Comment: to make it executable, change the attributes of the file using chmod command.
eg. Go to the directory and run,
sudo chmod 777 install
then run,
sudo ./install

Comment: @CR2:  Although, in this case, since it's presumably on CD, it's not a solution, but in general, that is not optimal advice. It assumes RWX for everyone, which is not necessarily true.  Much better to use the form that adds execute permission to the existing mode: `chmod +x path_to_app`.

Answer (score 0):

I have MATLAB running on Kubuntu 14.04. The reason you are unable to install it is because I think you are confusing the installation procedures with the downloaded files with the DVD installation procedures in the pdf.

After extracting your Linux installer (which should be "matlab_R2014a_glnxa64" for the latest release for Linux), open a terminal and change your directory to the installation folder, than type ./install.

According to your folder structure, the installer should be in "/home/pawan/Documents/matlab/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/"

Try

```
$ cd /home/pawan/Documents/matlab/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/
$ ./install
```

However, your folder name is "Matlab_Unix_2012a" which tells me you are using both an old version and it is probably the wrong operating system as well. I wouldn't know until you report back. If you are installing via an institution, I suggest getting the latest stable release for Linux. Ubuntu is explicitly mentioned.